# File download in AngularJS using API

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an API with returns a file(download). `Onclick` i call the api, but the file gets corrupted on download

```
exportService.getExportFile(queryParameter,function (results) {
        var file = new Blob([results], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;'});
        saveAs(file, 'filename.xlsx');
    }
}
```

The response from the API is in binary. How do i convert it to xlsx?

Comment: Please create jsfiddle for this problem, so we can look into code.